# How to run each thread on a slave at the same time and save results on same .jtl file

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, master-slave

i have a test plan that contains 3 threads (test scenarios) and each one read from csv file. how can i run each thread (test scenario) on a different slave at the same time and save results on one .jtl file?

the below command will run the whole test plan on all slaves and save results on one .jtl file:

```
jmeter -n -t InvoiceQ.jmx -l results.jtl -R 172.60.130.38,172.60.130.39,172.60.130.40
```

i need to run each thread on a slave and have one results file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html):

> If the test uses any data files, note that these are not sent across by the client so make sure that these are available in the appropriate directory on each server.

So just copy the CSV file onto all slave machines. JMeter master will collect the metrics from the slaves and store them into `results.jtl` file.

It's also possible to use plugins like [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) or [Redis Data Set Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/), in this case you won't need to copy the CSV file with test data to the slave machines

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, i don't have any issues with CSV files , it is located on the master and working fine, what i want to do is to run test scenario 1 on slave 1, and at the same time run test scenario 2 on slave 2 , the two scenarios are under one test plan , and to save results on one file. is that possible ?

Comment: If you need to run different parts of single test plan on different slaves you can consider using an [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and either [__machineIP() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) there or define different properties in [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) on each slave and use __P() function to read the property where needed.